# How can i set dropdownlist selectedIndex value from a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable value string i = xyz;
and i want to set dropdownlist selectedIndex value from a  variable value.

And I am trying this

```
dd_Interest.SelectedIndex = dd_Interest.Items.IndexOf(dd_Interest.Items.FindByText(categoryInterest1));
```

But its not working
How can i do this?
Waiting for reply

Comment: `dd_Interest.SelectedItem` ?

Comment: @zey according to me it should be "dd_Interest.SelectedItem.Value"

Comment: @raman , turn it to Answer :)

Comment: @zey done... :) please review, if you think there should be more info, please edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You not need to find the index of the selected item you just try the following code where you want to get the selected value of dropdownlist.

```
dd_Interest.SelectedItem.Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["searchInterest"]);
```

Or there some other ways like given below:

```
dd_Interest.Items.FindByText(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["searchInterest"])).Selected= true;
```

That's all.

Comment: But at this line an exception occur "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @HasasAliKhan please debug your code.. and firstly do one thing.. store the "categoryInterest1" in a variable then check whether the correct value is coming in that variable or not..then let me know the finding you will have

Comment: This is a querystring (Request.QueryString["searchInterest"];) and I get querystring value in a variable str_LastSearchInterest = Request.QueryString["searchInterest"]; and I get querystring(Interest|AP Chinese) and then i store AP Chinese in a variable categoryInterest1 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[0].ToString();
categoryInterest2 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[1].ToString();

Comment: please check the updated answer.. if this value exists in the DataSource by which you are binding the Dropdown then there could not be any issue. And one thing more do not forgot to bind the dropdownlist before this code...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dd_Interest.Items.FindByText("some text").Selected = true;
```

or

```
dd_Interest.Items.FindByValue("some value").Selected = true
```

You can also do a combination between both using Linq:

```
ListItem item = dd_Interest.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "some text"|| x.Value == "some value");

if (item != null)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @HasasAliKhan When you say it's not working ? What do you mean, I just tested it and it seems to be working fine ? What is the error that you're getting ?

Comment: @HasasAliKhan One more thing, what is `categoryInterest1` ? What's the value that it's holding ?

Comment: This is a querystring (Request.QueryString["searchInterest"];) and I get querystring value in a variable str_LastSearchInterest = Request.QueryString["searchInterest"]; and I get querystring(Interest|AP Chinese) and then i store AP Chinese in a variable categoryInterest1 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[0].ToString(); and Interest in categoryInterest2 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[1].ToString(); but I need categoryInterest1 value i.e "AP Chinese" and i get this value in a "dd_Interest" dropdownlist...

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just set the `SelectedItem` property

```
dd_Interest.SelectedItem= myString
```

Have a look here at the MSDN documentation

[ComboBox.SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx)

Comment: But at this line shows an exception "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: This is a querystring (Request.QueryString["searchInterest"];) and I get querystring value in a variable str_LastSearchInterest = Request.QueryString["searchInterest"]; and I get querystring(Interest|AP Chinese) and then i store AP Chinese in a variable categoryInterest1 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[0].ToString(); and Interest in categoryInterest2 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[1].ToString(); but I need categoryInterest1 value i.e "AP Chinese" and i get this value in a "dd_Interest" dropdownlist...

Answer (score 0):

I read in your comment, and I'm not sure what's the error you met. Anyway I saw something strange in your comment...

> This is a querystring (Request.QueryString["searchInterest"];)  and I
>   get querystring value in a variable  str_LastSearchInterest =
>   Request.QueryString["searchInterest"];  and I get
>   querystring(Interest|AP Chinese) and then i store **AP Chinese** in a
>   variable **categoryInterest1 =
>   str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[0].ToString();**  and **Interest** in 
>   **categoryInterest2 = str_LastSearchInterest.Split('|')[1].ToString();**

But after splited, at the index 0 should store "Interest" and index 1 should store "AP Chinese".
So categoryInterest1 value should be "Interest", not "AP Chinese". Then if you want to find index of "AP Chinese" and select it as default, you have to use **categoryInterest2** instead.